# WindowsError(31, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.') in arduino

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, espressif

Having board esp32 devkit v1, to get started with arduino ide (installed recommended boards for esp32) I marked board as`DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1` (as no other options as like `ESP32 DEVKIT V1` ) so upload gets this error

```
    esptool.py v2.6
Serial port COM3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "esptool.py", line 2959, in <module>
File "esptool.py", line 2952, in _main
File "esptool.py", line 2652, in main
File "esptool.py", line 222, in __init__
File "site-packages\serial\__init__.py", line 88, in serial_for_url
File "site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 62, in open
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': WindowsError(31, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.')
Failed to execute script esptool
the selected serial port Failed to execute script esptool
 does not exist or your board is not connected
```

so how do I upload my programs?
I would be highly obliged if you could please help me solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: are you sure COM3 is the correct port?

Comment: It's only available

Comment: is that trying to say that COM3 is the only one available? if you disconnect the ESP, does COM3 also disappear?

Comment: Have you installed the CP2102 drivers?

Comment: Yupp if I disconnect esp com3 disappeared

Comment: No I haven't install that drivers

Comment: I am facing trouble with the same error. Did it get solved? I tried with both the DM board and AI thinker, but this error doesn't seem to get removed at all

Answer (score 1):

I got this error.  Then switching USB ports fixed the problem.  Showed up on COM3 in either place. I just switched from a built-in USB port to on off a hub, and it started working.